# how can I solve composer update errors

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, composer-php

when I run composer update I get these errors, the problem is that I have php 7 installed but I don't know why am I getting this error (i'm using docker-compose)

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail[v0.3.0].
- rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail v0.3.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires silber/bouncer v1.0.0-rc.9 -> satisfiable by silber/bouncer[v1.0.0-rc.9].
- silber/bouncer v1.0.0-rc.9 requires php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 3
- Root composer.json requires stidges/country-flags ^1.0 -> satisfiable by stidges/country-flags[v1.0.0].
- stidges/country-flags v1.0.0 requires php ~5.6|~7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 4
- pusher/pusher-php-server[3.0.0, ..., v3.3.1] require php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.0 requires php >=5.4 <7.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.1 requires php >=5.4 <7.4 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server ~3.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[3.0.0, ..., v3.4.1].

And here is my php version

[image]

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

 

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Comment: Please share all error messages in readable form (that means: text), along with your attempts to resolve the problem. The given error message is posted to SO nearly weekly, so it should not be too hard to find a solution here

Comment: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail[v0.3.0].
    - rolandstarke/laravel-thumbnail v0.3.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I have no clue how can i solve because i already have php7 installed and i'm getting the php8 ERROR

Comment: How did you check that? Please share more details, like the **exact** command you are running, and the configuration of your Docker containers. Also, please share what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: here is the command : docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share way more details - nobody knows how you've configured your Docker containers

Comment: yes I did, should I add the dockerfile too?

Comment: ....if you think that helps, do it. Otherwise, please share what you've tried to resolve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue...

the log does tell you

> your php version (8.0.3) ...

So you have installed php8.0.3 as well ...

clean your php installation so that only php7.* is installed...

Depending on your OS there are variable commands

Comment: i'm using docker-compose

Comment: for clarification: you are using a docker container for laravel ? - fine... but your docker-compose is telling you, that you are running on php8.0.3

Comment: pls share your docker-compose.yml